# Displaying Mapbox tile meta data with UTF-8 characters

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm developing an interactive Mapbox based site that needs to support English and French language users. I've got the English version almost fully built up and am now working on the French version, but I'm running into some problems with the accents and extended characters.

In my application the user can click on a geographical shape, which then generates a popup that shows some additional meta data pulled from the source layer. The problem that I'm running into is that when I try to display the French meta data as html I'm getting funny characters for the accents. I realize this is a character encoding issue, but am not sure how to get around it.

I'm doing something like this (simplified to illustrate the problem):

```html
map.on('click', 'myInterestingLayer', (e) => {
  layerData = e.features[0].properties; // Convenience
  if (language === 'FR') {
    var description = buildHtmlFromData(layerData.nameFrHtml);
  }
      
        new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setMaxWidth(popupWidthForDevice)
            .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
            .setHTML(description)
            .addTo(map);
    }); // End on click
```

If I add a breakpoint to my code right where the click occurs and I print out the value of e.features[0].properties in the console I get:

nameFr: "Ottawa/a�roport international Macdonald-Cartier"

If I go to my Mapbox studio and look at the tileset, the metadata for nameFr displays with accents just fine. So the source data in the layer is fine, but it seems that when it gets pulled into my property array it doesn't retain its UTF-8 encoding.

I've set my page charset to UFT-8, and have managed to get accents to display in other popups. I'm only having a problem with the accents returned from the metadata in the Mapbox tilesets themselves.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit (Oct 6): It turns out it was encoding problem on my source tileset. Not exactly sure what happened, but once I re-converted my files to UTF-8 (no BOM) using Notepad++ they worked just fine

Comment: What is `buildHtmlFromData`? How are the mapbox tilesets and their metadata loaded?

Comment: That's a local function that takes in the name argument and adds some other contextual information around it. I get effectively the same result if replace it with  var description = layerData.nameFrHtml;

Comment: The tiles and metadata originate from GeoJson that was saved as UTF-8, and loaded into Mapbox studio.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was encoding problem on my source tileset. Not exactly sure what happened, but once I re-converted my files to UTF-8 (no BOM) using Notepad++ they worked just fine.